# Swig : How to wrap methods having as an argument a pointer function?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have this in a C/C++ project :

```
typedef void (*MyCallback) (MyHandle handle, void* context, MyResult result, ... );
int MyMethod(MyHandle handle, void* context, MyCallback cb);
```

Using **Swig**, I need to create a wrapper to MyMethod.

I read [this section](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn30) in the documentation, for the way of implementing pointers on functions (callbacks). But I don't see much how to apply it to my context above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many posts on SO about this. The solutions are never completely satisfactory because in Java you can't have free functions: all functions are methods (although you can have static methods). For regular methods, the callback must include the object (instance) that the method is part off. If you are free to put whatever you want in `context`, it might be possible. For instance if the dispatcher (whatever object calls the callbacks) calls cb like this:

```
 cb(context)
```

then cb can be a function that casts context to a class that contains a pointer to the instance for the callback, then it can call the method on that instance:

```
void MyJavaCallbackFn(MyHandle handle, void* context, MyResult result, ... )
{
    MyJavaCallback javaCb = (MyJavaCallback)context;
    (javaCb.obj.*->javaCb.method)(javaCb.arg1)
}
```

For this the MyJavaCallback would be a class you can define in SWIG .i file,

```
struct MyJavaCallback
{
    MyJavaObj* obj; // MyJavaObj has to be wrapped by SWIG
    MyJavaObj::Method* method;
    SomeArgClass arg1;
};
```

You would export a registration function via SWIG .i that takes a MyJavaCallback and calls MyMethod appropriately:

```
void registerJavaCb(MyJavaCallback context) 
{
     MyMethod(someHandle, context, MyJavaCallbackFn, ...)
}
```

This is all pseudocode, it is high level but that should give you general idea.